# applying colors on different object inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need help in applying color on the different object inside ng-repeat. I have 5 objects and i need them to have different colors. I understand i can do it with ng-class. however, the objects inside the ng-repeat are from constant injected thru the main controller and passed thru the modal window.

this is the modal html

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul ng-repeat="shift in item.shiftName">{{shift.shortcut}}
   <span>{{shift.title}}</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is the main controller where the constant is injected

```
vm.namesOfShift = SHIFT_NAMES;
vm.openScheduleModal = function (dayOfWeek){
  let popupArgs = {
    selectedDay: dayOfWeek,
    shiftName: SHIFT_NAMES
  };
  let template = '/components/chamModal/views/shiftModal.html';
  ModalService.open(popupArgs, template, 'lg', function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
};
```

and the constant

```
const SHIFT_NAMES = {
 MORNING: {
   title: 'Day Shift',
   shortcut: 'D',
   workHours: 8
  },
 NIGHT: {
   title: 'Night Shift',
   shortcut: 'N',
   workHours: 7.5
  },
 GRAVEYARD: {
   title: 'Graveyard Shift',
   shortcut: 'G',
   workHours: 10
 },
  OFF: {
    title: 'Off',
    shortcut: 'O',
    workHours: 24
 },
 LEAVE: {
   title: 'Leave',
   shortcut: 'L',
   workHours: 24}
 };
```

Thank you!

Comment: To what objects do you need the colors to be applied? And what colors do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the colors will be defined in the `SHIFT_NAMES` constant like this:

```
const SHIFT_NAMES = {
 MORNING: {
   title: 'Day Shift',
   shortcut: 'D',
   workHours: 8,
   color: 'orange'
  },
 NIGHT: {
   title: 'Night Shift',
   shortcut: 'N',
   workHours: 7.5,
   color: 'black'
  },
 GRAVEYARD: {
   title: 'Graveyard Shift',
   shortcut: 'G',
   workHours: 10,
   color: 'darkblue'
 },
  OFF: {
    title: 'Off',
    shortcut: 'O',
    workHours: 24,
    color: 'red'
 },
 LEAVE: {
   title: 'Leave',
   shortcut: 'L',
   workHours: 24,
   color: 'darkgreen'
 }
};
```

You can access it in your `ng-repeat` HTML code like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul ng-repeat="shift in item.shiftName">{{shift.shortcut}}
   <span style="color: {{ shift.color }}">{{shift.title}}</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The title will show the CSS color based on the color name found in the `SHIFT_NAMES` object.

Comment: thank you but i only want to apply the color on shortcut. Make it look like a box. i tried using ng-style with index however it fills up the whole row. @Dr. Cool